# How do I negotiate a higher parking allowance as an intern?

Tags: interviewing, negotiation, expenses

I am being hired as an intern for a company, and parking will be $177/month. They say they will reimburse me for $90. But I am almost going to have a masters degree, so I feel like maybe I can get more. But how do I politely ask for more?

Comment: Are you paying them to work for them? Forget about that.  Come and work for me.  I will let you work for me for free.

Comment: Can you car pool or take public transportation? Is there a cheaper lot/garage a few blocks away? Some companies have a program that allows you to pay your public transportation and parking expenses pre-tax, which will reduce your cost.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep- yes, true I can park nearby(maybe 10 min. though) but it's ok

Comment: Why would almost having a Master's degree matter in deciding if you get more for parking. Entry level is entry level. Lose the "I'm great because I have a master's degree" attitude. Likely most of your co-workers do too (or they wouldn't be looking at in terms in a Master's program) and have experience. You are the most junior of junior, expect to be treated as such.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - where do you pay $117 for parking? That's almost enough to rent an appartment in some places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the standard employee allowance is $90, e.g that's the allowance given to *everyone* in the company, you are unlikely to be successful, although asking for double the allowance because you're already making considerably less as a intern (if that's true), might be something the company would do. In case, you would simply say "thank you for extending the  employee allowance to interns as well, but is there any way to get more since my salary is less than that of a regular employee?"

However, if that is the allowance given only to *interns*, or you are not receiving a considerably smaller salary than an entry-level employee, or if you are receiving other benefits as an employee that are not typically given to interns, then I probably wouldn't push your luck. There's a fine line between looking too demanding and needy versus actually *being* needy.

If you cannot get to work any other way besides driving and parking, and you cannot afford to make up the difference on your own, then you might want to consider a cost-benefit analysis of taking that position in the first place.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! Well, luckily I can still afford it even at the current pay rate. I'll ask though.